# Order of including the header file

Tags: header-files, linker-errors

I am getting linking error in the following program.

```
//FILE: CDummyMessage.h

#idndef DUMMY_FILE
#define DUMMY_FILE
#include "stdafx.h"

class CDummyMessage(){
static int objCount1;
std::string;
};

#endif //DUMMY_FILE


// CDummyMessage.cpp
all the necessary definition 

//main cpp file: SmartPointerExample.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CDummyMessage.h"

int main(){
CDummyMessage* OBJ1= new CDummyMessage();
}
```

I am getting this linking error:-

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: "private: static int dummy::CDummyMessage::ObjCount1" (?ObjCount1@CDummyMessage@dummy@@0HA) already defined in DummyMessage.obj  C:\Users\Veil\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SmartPointerExample\SmartPointerExample\SmartPointerExample.obj
```

I am not able to figure out the reason of this linking error. I have made use of #ifndef directive that prevents duplicate inclusion of header file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have another file called `CDummyMessage.cpp` in your project ? and Visual studio Compiled that one  too.